# How to include an html table in a php script

Tags: php, html

I am new to HTML, I am trying to send emails in PHP with a table attachment, the best idea I could come up with was this:

```
$table = "<html>
              <head>
                    <style>
                    table {
                        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                        border-collapse: collapse;
                        width: 100%;
                    }

                    td, th {
                        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
                        text-align: left;
                        padding: 8px;
                    }

                    tr:nth-child(even) {
                        background-color: #dddddd;
                    }
                    </style>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                    <table>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Account</th>
                      <th>Credit used</th>
                      <th>Sent messages</th>
                      <th>Balance</th>
                    </tr>
                      <?php foreach ($statistics as $row) {
                    <tr>
                      <td>". $row["username"] ."</td>
                      <td>". $row["creditUsed"] ."</td>
                      <td>". $row["sentMessages"] ."</td>
                      <td>". $row["balance"] ."</td>
                    </tr>
                     }
                     ?>
                    </body>
                    </html>
                  </table>";
```

This worked fine until I added the loop, it is treated like a string and gives the error `Notice: Array to string conversion` I do not know how to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage of Quotes is wrong in your code.

Try to make HTML structure in proper manner like this:-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table {
                font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
            }

            td, th {
                border: 1px solid #dddddd;
                text-align: left;
                padding: 8px;
            }

            tr:nth-child(even) {
                background-color: #dddddd;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Account</th>
          <th>Credit used</th>
          <th>Sent messages</th>
          <th>Balance</th>
        </tr>

          <?php foreach ($statistics as $row) {?>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $row["username"];?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row["creditUsed"];?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row["sentMessages"];?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row["balance"];?></td>
                    </tr>
         }
         ?>
    </body>
</html>
</table>
```

Note:-

Make sure page extension must be `.php` not `.html`

Make sure `$statistics` is set+not-empty+available on this page. (have some values too)

***Since you want it to use in `PhpMailer` so do like below:-***

```
$table = 
"<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table {
                font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
            }

            td, th {
                border: 1px solid #dddddd;
                text-align: left;
                padding: 8px;
            }

            tr:nth-child(even) {
                background-color: #dddddd;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Account</th>
              <th>Credit used</th>
              <th>Sent messages</th>
              <th>Balance</th>
            </tr>";

            <?php foreach ($statistics as $row) {
                  $table .= "<tr><td>". $row["username"] ."</td><td>". $row["creditUsed"] ."</td><td>". $row["sentMessages"] ."</td><td>". $row["balance"] ."</td></tr>";
            }
            ?>
$table .= "</body></html></table>";
```

Comment: I have edited your answer a bit, it works now, thanks.

Comment: @Randoroxford  glad to help  you :):)

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use following structure with HTML:

```
<?php foreach ($statistics as $row): ?> 
   <tr>
     <td><?= $row["username"]; ?></td>
     <td><?= $row["creditUsed"]; ?></td>
     <td><?= $row["sentMessages"]; ?></td>
     <td><?= $row["balance"]; ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```